# Crash issue while picking a large size image from the iphone library in iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone

i am getting a crash issue(it is due to low memory) while picking up the a large image (3.5 MB) from the photo library in iphone 3G. The problem is only with iphone 3G while it is working fine in iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4. I am saving this image to my iphone library from my email, and it seems that the image saved to the library is not getting optimized. Is this a bug ? Can anybody suggest me a solution. It is possible to restrict the user from picking very large image from the library in iphone 3G. I tried picking up this large image using the sample application given by apple, and it is crashing even with that.

Comment: I think there is no way you can restrict user to pick large image. But I also think that the crash is not because they pick big image. 3.5MB is not so big comparing to an iPhone memory

Comment: 3.5MB might well be way too big compared to the iPhone GPU's texture memory, which is the critical resource when playing with large images.  The 2G and 3G are known to have problems with textures larger than 1k by 1k.  The 3GS and 4 have newer GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the crash happening when you pick the image, or when you try to put the image in a UIImageView? If the latter, you may need to scale the image to a smaller resolution before placing it in the UIImageView. I have seen recommendations that image sizes greater than 1024 x 1024 should be avoided in UIImageView.

You can do this using code like the following:

```
if (image.size.width > 1024 || image.size.height > 1024) {
    // resize the image
    float actualHeight = image.size.height;
    float actualWidth = image.size.width;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = self.frame.size.width/self.frame.size.height;

    if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
        imgRatio = self.frame.size.height / actualHeight;
        actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = self.frame.size.height;
    } else {
        imgRatio = self.frame.size.width / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    imageToDraw = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Note that imageToDraw is a UIImage * declared outside of this code, and is the final image that can be put into the UIImageView. This code came from a method in a custom view that I wrote, so where you see self.frame in the code, you can replace with whatever frame you are scaling the image into.